# I can't figure out the problems in my Kotlin code?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

1. In `LoginViewModel`, I can't figure out what I should write in "if (result is ....) because whatever I write in turns out red.
2. In `LoginRepository` the " when is ->" turns red. I don't know why?
3. And in `LoginDataSource` I don't know how to solve the code.

I would appreciate any help.

**LoginViewModel:**

```
fun login(username: String, password: String) {
    // can be launched in a separate asynchronous job
    val result: String = loginRepository.login(username, password).toString()

    if (result is Success.data) {
        _loginResult.value =
            LoginResult(success = LoggedInUserView(displayName = "Login Success"))
    } else {
        _loginResult.value = LoginResult(error = R.string.login_failed)
    }
}
```

**LoginRepository:**

```
fun login(username: String, password: String) {
    // handle login
    val result = dataSource.login(username, password)

    when (result) {
        is ->  Success(data = LoggedInUser(displayName = "Login Success"))   
    } 
}
```

**LoginDataSource:**

```
fun login(username: String, password: String): Result.Success<LoggedInUser> {
    try {
        //TODO:handleloggedInUserauthentication 
    }
}

fun logout() {
     // TODO: revoke authentication
}
```

Comment: What is `loginRepository`, put the class in the question, and why are you checking that `result: String` is of type `Result.data`? In second code, you are checking type of result but you never declared which type it should be to after the `is` operator.

Answer (score 0):

1. If I correctly understand `Success` class inherits `Result` class:

   ```
   val result = loginRepository.login(username, password)
   if (result is Success) {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Change signature of `login` function in LoginRepository to return `Result`:

   ```
   fun login(username: String, password: String): Result.Success<LoggedInUser> {
        // ...
        return when (result) {
            is Success ->  Success(data = LoggedInUser(displayName = "Login Success"))
            else -> Error()
        }
   }
   ```
3. In login Data Source make request to whatever API you use, handle response, create and return `Success` or `Error` object depending on response.